# Warning: Partition X does not end on cylinder boundary. Should I care/how to fix?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fdisk

My output of

```
fdisk -l
```

is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750 GB, 750153761280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sda1   *           1        5860    47070418   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            5861       91201   685493550    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            5861        6103     1943865   82  Linux swap
Warning: Partition 5 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda6            6104       91201   683541652   83  Linux
Warning: Partition 6 does not end on cylinder boundary.
```

`/dev/sda1` is my root partion, `/dec/sda5` is swap and `/dev/sda6` us my home partition.

I'm not sure if these warnings are new, or if I had them since I set up the sytsem in the first place.

What do these warnings tell me? Should I care or be worried? And if so, how to fix it?

I searched the internet, but found a lot of different informations, some of them obviously wrong, so I hope to find some answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They tell you exactly what they say.  [No, you shouldn't care about that.  Your cylinders are complete fictions and no actual operating system, not even MS-DOS, has actually itself cared about such alignment.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/disc-partition-alignment.html#Track)  This is a pointless message from `fdisk`, which is over three years behind other disc partitioning utilities and [showing no signs of improving](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=491748).  Get yourself an up-to-date partitioning tool that doesn't have this silliness, and that does 4KiB alignment or similar, such as `gdisk`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I guessed it would be nothing to worry about. Btw. I'm using `fdisk` only to get a quick overview of my disks and partitions, for partition management I usually use `parted` or `gparted` anyway.

Comment: This is *almost* correct: MS-DOS did actually care, but only in certain extremely specific circumstances that apparently few bothered to investigate in depth. Namely: when you have a ‘CHS’ extended partition (type ID 0x05), the Extended Boot Record must be located at the beginning of a cylinder, as otherwise DOS will miscompute where the corresponding logical drive is located. This does not apply to primary partitions or ‘LBA’ EBRs (type id 0x0f). The requirement stems from the way in which DOS remembers partition offsets in its internal data structures.