# Understand warnings after "fdisk -l" commands

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, fdisk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Warning: Partition X does not end on cylinder boundary. Should I care/how to fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/339288/warning-partition-x-does-not-end-on-cylinder-boundary-should-i-care-how-to-fix)

fdisk -l it gives me this scenario:

> Disk /dev/sda: 500 GB, 500105249280 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>
> Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
>
> /dev/sda1 * 1 3911 31415076 7 HPFS/NTFS
> /dev/sda2 3912 7669 30178102 7 HPFS/NTFS
> /dev/sda3 7670 10963 26451022 83 Linux
> /dev/sda4 10964 60801 400315702 5 Extended
> /dev/sda6 10964 60303 396315517 83 Linux
> Warning: Partition 6 does not end on cylinder boundary
> /dev/sda5 60304 60801 3992152 82 Linux swap
> Warning: Partition 5 does not end on cylinder boundary

What does it mean those warnings???

Comment: Read this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/339288/warning-partition-x-does-not-end-on-cylinder-boundary-should-i-care-how-to-fix